# PIPESTATUS variable is empty

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

I'm working on a Linux server and noticed that the PIPESTATUS array variable is always empty.
I'm on bash v4.1.2(1)-release

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.1.2(1)-release
$ false | true | false
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]} # returns nothing (empty)
```

What could be the reason? I checked online forums including stack exchange but didn't find a good answer

Comment: Does it also happen in a bash session started as `bash --norc`? Is it possible `bash` was started with a `PIPESTATUS` variable in the environment (with empty value)? I can reproduce with `env PIPESTATUS= bash --norc`. Work around: `unset PIPESTATUS`

Comment: `unset PIPESTATUS` worked, thank you! @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: So, does this mean if a bash variable is initialized at the start, it won't update that variable  when it should?

Comment: Also, it's strange, the default shell in my server was korn shell and I manually switched to bash using simple `bash` command, I haven't actually initialized PIPESTATUS variable when starting bash shell

Comment: What's the output of `typeset -p PIPESTATUS`.

Comment: You can start `bash` with `bash --login -o xtrace` to try and see if a `PIPESTATUS` variable is being assigned as a scalar by one of the startup files if it doesn't come from the environmetn.

Comment: `typeset -p PIPESTATUS` returned `declare -a PIPESTATUS='()'`

Comment: Is that before or after the `unset PIPESTATUS` that restores it?

Comment: I logged out and opened a new bash shell and then ran `typeset -p PIPESTATUS` so it is before `unset PIPESTATUS`

Comment: That would suggest it's a different case from the one I suggest in my answer. I can't reproduce your case. Does the `bash --login -o xtrace` give a clue as to what happens to that variable? What OS is it? bash-4.1 is ancient and 4.1.2 not even the latest patch release there. That bash may even be vulnerable to shellshock!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That can happen if `$PIPESTATUS` has been declared as a scalar variable or anything that is not an array or has been made readonly, either by you or code found in or through your `~/.bashrc` / `~/.bash_profile`... or because there was `PIPESTATUS=` in the environment when `bash` was started.

You can check the type, attributes and value of `$PIPESTATUS` with `typeset -p PIPESTATUS`.

Then `$PIPESTATUS` stays scalar and is not automatically converted to array to store the exit statuses of pipeline components:

```
$ env PIPESTATUS= bash -c 'false | true; typeset -p PIPESTATUS'
declare -x PIPESTATUS=""
$ bash -c 'PIPESTATUS=; false | true; typeset -p PIPESTATUS'
declare -- PIPESTATUS=""
$ bash -c 'typeset -A PIPESTATUS; false | true; typeset -p PIPESTATUS'
declare -A PIPESTATUS
$ bash -c 'readonly PIPESTATUS; false | true; typeset -p PIPESTATUS'
declare -r PIPESTATUS
```

Except for the `readonly` case, that can be worked around by converting the variable back to array or by unsetting it:

```
typeset -a PIPESTATUS # beware it can affect the scope if run from a function
```

```
unset -v PIPESTATUS
```